# What is the ROC for this discrete signal:

Tags: discrete-signals, z-transform

$$ x(k)=4[u(k-2)-u(k)*δ(k-3)]$$

I found that the $\mathcal{Z}$ transform of the signal is $X(z)=4/(z^2)$.

What would the ROC be?

Comment: Is this homework? If so, label it with the `homework` tag.

Comment: No, it's not homework, school hasn't started yet. It's just an exercise i'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

Remember that the ROC is the region in the $z$-plane for which the series

$$X(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x[n]z^{-n}\tag{1}$$

converges. Since you've found $X(z)$ you also know that $x[n]=4\delta[n-2]$, i.e. there's only one value of $n$ for which $x[n]$ is not equal to zero. What does that mean for the convergence of $(1)$?

Comment: @angie: No, the ROC has nothing to do with $n$, it's about the allowed values of $z$. So for which values of $z$ does the "series" $\ldots+0+0+4z^{-2}+0+0+\ldots$ converge, that means have a finite value?

Answer (score 0):

So the $\mathcal{Z}$ transform is $4z^{-2}$ so that the actual signal is $4\delta[n-2]$.  [From this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform#Table_of_common_Z-transform_pairs), that means that the ROC is all of $z$ except the origin.

Comment: You kind of spoiled it ... ;)

Comment: Mea cupla, mea maxima culpa. :-)